# Getting next date based on start date in Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a scenario where, I have to get the receiving dates based on the delivery dates in the system.

The sample system I am referring to is a shopping cart and for every order, the receiving date can be any of the 5 dates.

For Example,

```
SHOP_ID         CITY        ST  MON TUE WED THU FRI
0566567890823   CARLSBAD    CA  M           H   
1950567890821   SAN DIEGO   CA  M           H   
2171567890842   ESCONDIDO   CA      T       H   
1028567890864   CALEXICO    CA      T       H   
1950567890849   SAN DIEGO   CA                  F
2171567890878   ESCONDIDO   CA          W       F
1274567890882   CHULA VISTA CA      T       H   
2414567890891   EL CAJON    CA  M               
0634567890804   ESCONDIDO   CA  M           H   
1274567890845   CHULA VISTA CA          W       F
0634567890828   ESCONDIDO   CA                  F
2414567890897   EL CAJON    CA          W       F
```

So for shop '0566567890823', if delivery date is tomorrow (21st March), the pickup date is the very nearest Monday (24th March), as the shop accepts the orders on Monday and Thursday.

similarly, if delivery date is Tuesday (25th March), the shop accepts the orders on Thursday (27th March).

Can someone please help me with a query which can give me the possible pickup date based on the shop id and the delivery date

Below are the create and insert scripts for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE  "DELIVERY_DETAILS" (
"SHOP_ID" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"CITY" VARCHAR2(15),
"STATE" VARCHAR2(15),
"MON" CHAR(1), 
"TUE" CHAR(1), 
"WED" CHAR(1), 
"THU" CHAR(1), 
"FRI" CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('0566567890823', 'CARLSBAD', 'CA', 'M', '', '', 'H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('1950567890821', 'SAN DIEGO', 'CA', 'M', '', '', 'H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('2171567890842', 'ESCONO', 'CA', '', 'T', '','H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('1028567890864', 'CALEXICO', 'CA', '', 'T', '', 'H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('1950567890849', 'SAN DIEGO', 'CA', '', '', '', '', 'F');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('2171567890878', 'ESCONDIDO', 'CA', '', '', 'W', '', 'F');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('1274567890882', 'CHULA VISTA', 'CA', '','T', '','H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('2414567890891', 'EL CAJON', 'CA', 'M', '', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('0634567890804', 'ESCONDIDO', 'CA', 'M', '', '', 'H', '');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('1274567890845', 'CHULA VISTA', 'CA', '', '', 'W', '', 'F');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('0634567890828', 'ESCONDIDO', 'CA', '', '', '', '', 'F');
INSERT INTO DELIVERY_DETAILS VALUES
('2414567890897', 'EL CAJON', 'CA', '', '', 'W', '', 'F');
```

The input is delivery date which is system driven (can be a system date as well) and output is the possible pickup date of the shop.

Similar to the above example, if it is 'M', the pickup would be nearest next Monday

Thanks a lot

Comment: In my case, I am a kind of online media which delivers to the shop and shop picks it. So, Delivery is the first activity and Pickup/Receiving is the second

Comment: I am novice to this and so I am not able to get the exact pitch as of now. The above data is what I cooked up, so that it is understandable.

Comment: @realspirituals - Please find my comments edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would [unpivot](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55205) the data first.

```
select * from (
  select *
  from delivery_details
  where shop_id = '2171567890878'
  )
unpivot(
    ind for week_day in (
                        mon as 'monday',
                        tue as 'thursday',
                        wed as 'wednesday',
                        thu as 'thursday',
                        fri as 'friday'
                        )
        );

|       SHOP_ID |      CITY | STATE |  WEEK_DAY | IND |
|---------------|-----------|-------|-----------|-----|
| 2171567890878 | ESCONDIDO |    CA | wednesday |   W |
| 2171567890878 | ESCONDIDO |    CA |    friday |   F |
```

Once you have this, use [NEXT_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions098.htm#SQLRF00672) to get the next pickup date. If your
delivery day equals the pickup day, next_day function will give you one week later date. If you don't want that to happen, use case statement to return the delivery_date.

```
select shop_id, city, state,
       case when to_char(date'2014-03-21','fmday') = week_day
          then date'2014-03-21'
          else next_day(date'2014-03-21',week_day)
       end pickup_date
from (
  select * from (
    select *
    from delivery_details
    where shop_id = '2171567890878'
    )
  unpivot(
      ind for week_day in (
                        mon as 'monday',
                        tue as 'thursday',
                        wed as 'wednesday',
                        thu as 'thursday',
                        fri as 'friday'
                        )
        )
  );

|       SHOP_ID |      CITY | STATE |                  PICKUP_DATE |
|---------------|-----------|-------|------------------------------|
| 2171567890878 | ESCONDIDO |    CA | March, 26 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
| 2171567890878 | ESCONDIDO |    CA | March, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Then just apply MIN to get the nearest date.

```
select min(
       case when to_char(date'2014-03-21','fmday') = week_day
          then date'2014-03-21'
          else next_day(date'2014-03-21',week_day)
       end
       ) pickup_date
from (
  select * from (
    select *
    from delivery_details
    where shop_id = '2171567890878'
    )
  unpivot(
      ind for week_day in (
                        mon as 'monday',
                        tue as 'thursday',
                        wed as 'wednesday',
                        thu as 'thursday',
                        fri as 'friday'
                        )
        )
  );

|                  PICKUP_DATE |
|------------------------------|
| March, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3586/14)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper solution. But you can think of these functions and check.

```
SELECT T1.*,
       DELIVERY,
       LEAST ( NVL ( ABS ( M - DELIVERY ), 8 ),
               NVL ( ABS ( T - DELIVERY ), 8 ),
               NVL ( ABS ( W - DELIVERY ), 8 ),
               NVL ( ABS ( H - DELIVERY ), 8 ),
               NVL ( ABS ( F - DELIVERY ), 8 ) )
          LEASTVAL,
FROM   (SELECT SHOP_ID,
               CASE
                  WHEN MON IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'MONDAY' )
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END
                  AS M,
               CASE
                  WHEN TUE IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'TUESDAY' )
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END
                  AS T,
               CASE
                  WHEN WED IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'WEDNESDAY' )
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END
                  AS W,
               CASE
                  WHEN THU IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'THURSDAY' )
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END
                  AS H,
               CASE
                  WHEN FRI IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE ), 'FRIDAY' )
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END
                  AS F
        FROM   DELIVERY_DETAILS
        WHERE  SHOP_ID = 0566567890823
        AND    COALESCE ( MON,
                          TUE,
                          WED,
                          THU,
                          FRI )
                  IS NOT NULL) T1,
       (SELECT TO_DATE ( '21-MAR-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) AS DELIVERY FROM DUAL) T2;
```